# Sending data back upon receiving POST request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I'm posting data to my server from my chrome extension using a standard jQuery ajax POST request. However, I'd like the server, upon receiving the POST request, to send back a javascript file to the chrome extension.. How can I do this? Do I have to set up a new POST request server side? Or can I send something back using the 'response'?

Client.js

```
   request("https://61d6b1ac.ngrok.io/api/panels/hitme", "post", "JSON", {apples})
    .done(function(res){

    })
      })
   function request(url, method, dataType, data){
   return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: method,
    dataType: dataType,
    data: data
    })
    }
```

Server.js

```
    function sendJSfile(req, res) {
    var body = req.body.apples
    console.log(body)

    if (body.length >= 3) {
        console.log("Long!")
    } else{
        console.log("Short!")
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/javascript"});
        fs.createReadStream("./example.js").pipe(res);
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just echo/write/put it out from server side.

```
$.post('somurl',{},function(returnData){
  //do something with returnData
});
```

Although it is HIGHLY recommended NOT to inject javascript into the dom dynamically. You would have to use a function like eval() to excecute it which opens you up to all kinds of trouble.

Comment: I've amended my question with the code. I don't understand how to put it out from the server side? My code is currently set to do this, but it doesn't send the example.js to the client..No errors appear but example.js doesn't run?